# How to stop coffee from spilling when drinking from sipper lid?

Tags: drinks

When I drink coffee through the sipper lid, it always seems to spill. What could I be doing wrong/ how can I avoid this?

[image]

Comment: Me too, so I remove the lid and drink from the cup. The lid is only there to stop it spilling while you carry it somewhere else, and the hole is only there if you are desperate to drink coffee while walking. The hack is to sit down.

Comment: @WeatherVane sitting down doesn't really help, I sometimes drink from such a cup while driving, and most of the times if I forget to remove that lid, it spills. Ah, unless you mean sit down, remove the lid, then drink. Yes that would work. :)

Comment: I cannot recommend drinking a coffee while driving. You are not in proper control of the vehicle and if you spill hot coffee *then* it could be disasterous for anybody else. The point about sitting down is that you are in control of the coffee, and can remove the lid, as it does not need to be  spillproof then.

Answer (score 2):

> What could I be doing wrong

Nothing. The problem is bad shape of the hole in the cover from which we are supposed to drink.

> how can I avoid this?

Either just remove the lid before drinking, as Weather Vane mentioned in [this comment](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/27534/how-to-stop-coffee-from-spilling-when-drinking-from-sipper-lid#comment39684_27534), or you can try buying/getting a straw:

[image: straw inside the cup]